# Repaint Issue in linux paltform

Tags: java, swing

When I run my application in Linux platform it throws below exception and couldn't see any component in the frame/panel rather it shows grayed out screen and the component will be shown when we click/move  mouse point above the components. Also I have dynamic test update button and this also getting updated each mouse move above the button.

Note: This same application is working fine with windows platform.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 | Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.getMinimumSize(BasicButtonUI.java:352)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1714)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.BorderLayout.minimumLayoutSize(BorderLayout.java:651)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1651)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1636)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1716)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.FlowLayout.minimumLayoutSize(FlowLayout.java:448)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1651)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1636)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1716)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:1094)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:893)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(GridBagLayout.java:2052)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(GridBagLayout.java:2008)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(GridBagLayout.java:789)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:669)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:124)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:642)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:612)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: We are not wizard, show us your code.

Comment: This seems very vague... Maybe try the "standard" debugging strategy of removing stuff from GUI until it works. Then you know what is causing the problem. Then, if googling does not give you an answer outright, you can write a minimal app which reproduces the error, and ask again at SO: "why this code works on Windows but fails on Linux".

Comment: Where are your classes, these only look like part of the error, it's only swing and awt.

Comment: This exception might simply be caused by inappropriate Swing components usage. You will have to show a small code example that represents this problem and causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so let's dig your stacktrace for a while:

> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.getMinimumSize(BasicButtonUI.java:352)

Let's have a look at the code there:

```
public Dimension getMinimumSize(JComponent c) {
    Dimension d = getPreferredSize(c);
View v = (View) c.getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey);
if (v != null) {
    d.width -= v.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS) - v.getMinimumSpan(View.X_AXIS); // Line 352
}
return d;
}
```

OK, so your `NullPointerException` is coming from `getPreferredSize(JComponent c)` which returns `null`.

So in the end, either your button contains additional components or the look and feel chosen on Linux returns a `null` value (for whatever reason which is about impossible to find out with so less details).

Comment: Thanks alot. I do feel this may be due to look and feel only. I will test with different look and feel for Linux.

Comment: Can any one suggest like to customize the look and feel to support Linux platform. I tried to use GTK look and feel but the GUI behave stranger and i wanted similar as windows look.

Comment: button color is not getting updates rather showed dynamically when i run my application.

Comment: Thanks. I got the solution by setting the button minimum size
button.setMiniumSize(button.size())